# Probability of flipping a coin 20 times and, given that the number of heads is twice or more the number of tails, obtaining an odd number of heads

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, binomial-distribution

First of all, I have obtained using the binomial distribution that the probability of obtaining twice or more heads than tails is $0.0577$
(value which corresponds with the solution of the textbook). However, I am having problems with the conditional probability of the title.

I know that the possible number of heads that verify the condition are $14,15,16,17,18,19$
or $20$, and only three of them are odd. So, I thought of $3/20$ but the solution must be $0.2754$. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: For first question, you knew that the list of all valid counts was (14, 15,16,17,18,19, 20), and you did not say 7/20, but the correct answer 0.0577.  Why do you change method when the list is (15,17,19) instead of (14, 15, 16,17,18,19,20) ?

Comment: Oh, it's true @Lourrran. So, using the same method, I obtain $\frac{(\binom{20}{15} +\binom{20}{17}+\binom{20}{19})*0.5^{20}}{0.0577}=0.2756$. Thanks again for your comment.